# Conditional in select count

Tags: php, select

I count the number of comments of each post. And it works:

```
$numComments = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_post) FROM comments WHERE id_post = '". $row["id"]."' ");  
// it works if I do this: echo mysql_result($numComents,0);
```

But I prefer to show the number of comments only if there is any comments. But I have problems with the conditional.

```
if ($numComments > 0){
    echo mysql_result($numComments,0); 
}else{

}
```

How can I say that If there is comments show the number. If there is 0 comments don't show anything ( I don't want it to show "there is 0 comments")

Comment: Do you want it to show `There is  comments.`, or something else?

Comment: You're pretty much done - what's wrong with your `if` clause?

Comment: What do you have before/after the conditional? It seems like you'd simply just want to include the entirety of your text in the conditional.... `if true -> echo 'There are $numComentaris comments; else -> echo 'There are no comments';`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` extension, it's being deprecated: PHP themselves strongly recommend using PDO/mysqli_*, both of which support _prepared statements_

Comment: @David. I have no problem to show there is comments or something like. I don't put it here just to simplify the problem. The difficulty is with the conditional

Comment: @Blueboye I don't get any error. It shows the write number of comments but the problem is that when there is no comments it  shows 0 and I am trying that it shows nothing in this case.

Comment: @Elias: I'm just beginning with php and I am learning alone. I learned  specially from W3c that I thought was the official guide. I think they say nothing of PDO? If W3c is not the best place, where can I go? (I studied marketing in the university, so I need something easy to begin with)

Comment: [W3C is rubbish](http://w3fools.com), don't use it. If you want the official docs, just use [PHP.net](http://www.php.net), add `/somefunction` to the url to go to the man pages. for example: [mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect), and notice the big red warning-thing, advising you _not_ to use the `mysql_*` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_post) FROM comments WHERE id_post = '". $row["id"]."' "); 
$numComments = mysql_result($result,0);
if ( $numComments  > 0) {
 echo $numComments ; 
 } else {
   //do something...
 }
```

Comment: It works perfect and it is clear. But I still don't understand why it did not work without the var?

Comment: Without the var? which variable?

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a resultset resource. You need to traverse that resource to get to the row/column returned. Here's the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$number_of_rows = mysql_fetch_row($numComments)[0];

echo $number_of_rows > 0 ? $number_of_rows : '';
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, I'm a beginner. Can you explain it. It does not work, perhaps it is me that I am doing something wrong but If I copy paste in Dreaweaver it shows an error in your first line ?